# navbar(menu) is getting overlapped by body element

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, overlapping

I was trying to create a simple page with html css but start facing problem with the navbar. 
I placed a transparent box with some text in the body. But as the page is scrolled thru the box is hovering above the menu. Found a related topic "Menu overlapping the body" but didn't see anything to fix my issue. [[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w7qwfme3/2/)]

```
<head>
div.box {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 20px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.box p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

<div class="navbar" style="display:table;">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Menu</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 style="color:white; text-align:center">Some text some text </h2>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set to `nav`     `z-index: 1;`
**You Can Also Learn z-index poperty and wow it work** [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
body {margin:0;}

div.box {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 20px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
 
div.box p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  
  <div class="box">
    <h2 style="color:white; text-align:center">Some text some text </h2>
           <p>Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text... </p>
           <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    
  </div>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: why this much z-index?

Comment: I know but i give it to be sure

Comment: never do this. becuase when project get larger it big headache for you.

Comment: you too  @לבני מלכה :)

Answer (score 0):

just add  `z-index: 1` to .navbar.

Answer (score 0):

just add z-index to navbar. it could be 1 to 9 or until you get what u want you can increase the z-index .